# Image in responsive div

Tags: css

Here is my codepen with the problem : http://codepen.io/Golgota/pen/gwvGGj

And my CSS :

```
.bloc {
  background-color:white;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
  .bloc {
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

I have 3 responsive div `.bloc` I would like to keep them at the same height. The problem comes from the images which have different sizes.

Is there a way to have 3 `.bloc` with the same height without changing the images' resolutions or scrolling ?

Cheers !

Comment: take a look at my code, may be that will help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/* item styles */
.item-image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.item-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.item-content {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #72cffa;
}
.item-text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

/* centering styles for jsbin */
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
html {
  display: table;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Css aspect ratio to have images of same height</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Css aspect ratio to have images of same height">
  <!-- include bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="item-image">
          <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">
          <div class="item-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="item-image">
          <img src="http://s11.favim.com/orig/160919/forum-communaute-topic-9808-hd-putlocker-watch-hell-or-high-water-online-full-movie-1080p-Favim.com-4740061.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">
          <div class="item-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="item-image">
          <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">
          <div class="item-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec velit nulla. Cras finibus mollis dolor, ac rhoncus diam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin gravida iaculis orci eget malesuada. Morbi pulvinar, purus sit amet porta laoreet, quam orci fermentum leo, in interdum ligula elit id magna. Nam justo massa, ultrices eget dictum vitae, porttitor eget eros. 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [object fit](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit), but check the support first,

you can do this,

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block-holder .bloc {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 32.66%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.block-holder .bloc:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
  margin: 0 1%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-holder">
  <div class="bloc">
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita itaque ipsa sit quibusdam optio cumque labore necessitatibus. Eaque soluta ut excepturi rerum repudiandae harum nisi doloremque cupiditate exercitationem voluptatem tempora.
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="bloc">
    <img src="http://s11.favim.com/orig/160919/forum-communaute-topic-9808-hd-putlocker-watch-hell-or-high-water-online-full-movie-1080p-Favim.com-4740061.jpeg" />
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita itaque ipsa sit quibusdam optio cumque labore necessitatibus. Eaque soluta ut excepturi rerum repudiandae harum nisi doloremque cupiditate exercitationem voluptatem tempora.
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="bloc">
    <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" />
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita itaque ipsa sit quibusdam optio cumque labore necessitatibus. Eaque soluta ut excepturi rerum repudiandae harum nisi doloremque cupiditate exercitationem voluptatem tempora.
      <p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He asked this `I have 3 responsive div .bloc I would like to keep them at the same height. The problem comes from the images which have different sizes` not the full width image you

Comment: @Joyson check the snippet again,

Comment: but adding my code is enough to do that that simple code `.bloc img{height:250px; width:100%;}` on his linked codepen

Comment: check and make sure that i might be wrong on answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just changed the image `min-height` into pixels rather than %.

```css
body {
  background-color:orange;
  padding: 5%;
  margin:auto;
}

.bloc {
  background-color:white;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  min-height: 270px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
  .bloc {
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita itaque ipsa sit quibusdam optio cumque labore necessitatibus. Eaque soluta ut excepturi rerum repudiandae harum nisi doloremque cupiditate exercitationem voluptatem tempora.
  <p>
</div>
<div class="bloc">
  <img src="http://s11.favim.com/orig/160919/forum-communaute-topic-9808-hd-putlocker-watch-hell-or-high-water-online-full-movie-1080p-Favim.com-4740061.jpeg"/>
   <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita itaque ipsa sit quibusdam optio cumque labore necessitatibus. Eaque soluta ut excepturi rerum repudiandae harum nisi doloremque cupiditate exercitationem voluptatem tempora.
    <p>
</div>
<div class="bloc">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg"/>
   <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita itaque ipsa sit quibusdam optio cumque labore necessitatibus. Eaque soluta ut excepturi rerum repudiandae harum nisi doloremque cupiditate exercitationem voluptatem tempora.
    <p>
</div>
```